# On OS 9.2.1, how can you access shared files from windows computers?

Tags: network, classic-mac-os

I'm a total newbie Mac user. I got a Powerbook 3 Pismo off of ebay, got OS 9.2.1 installed, and enabled file sharing. Web browsing is working and I have an IP address.

How do I access the shared folder from my windows 8 machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OS 9 has no built-in support for Windows file sharing. There were third-party file sharing applications for Mac OS to allow access to Windows networks, and there were also Windows server tools which could allow Mac access to Windows servers. One tool I remember using was DAVE, from Thursby software. It used to be a Windows networking kit for Mac, but has morphed into something else now. If you found an older version it might work, but I doubt it would be compatible with the latest Windows.

I'd recommend looking for an FTP server for your Windows machine and a FTP client for your Mac.

Comment: I was thinking about the FTP too, it's how I easily get from MSDOS to Windows. If no one has anymore answers by the end of the day, I'll mark you as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: why wait, just join in and give him a + as I did, and while at it you got one 2.

Answer (score 1):

Not a specific answer to the question, but one alternative is to use a FAT32 formatted USB stick. This is compatible with OS 9. Setting up an FTP server to migrate files back and forth is handy in the moment, but going back and forth between the two systems to turn on the server, connect, move files probably takes longer than just putting on the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the aforementioned Thursby DAVE, which surprisingly is still an active commercial product, another option would be Connectix DoubleTalk, which is apparently [abandonware obtainable from the Macintosh Garden](http://macintoshgarden.org/apps/connectix-doubletalk).

Unlike DAVE which provides both client and server SMB functionality, DoubleTalk is only a SMB client, not a server, so you'd need to perform your file-transferring from the old Mac's end with that -- i.e., Windows won't be able to see any shares on the Mac, but the Mac would be able to find and access shares on Windows. I found [this write-up explaining the process](https://happymacs.wordpress.com/2014/06/21/network-your-classic-macintosh-with-windows-part-2-using-doubletalk/).

Comment: DoubleTalk doesn't work as expected with newer Windows (later than XP). Probably related to SMB version, but I was unable to achieve good result even with disabling SMB2 and enabling SMB1 only.